# Cross-Browser CSS margin and float positioning

Tags: css, html, positioning, css-float

Trying position two divs with the left one being a sidebar that is 200px wide and the right one taking up the rest of the screen. I have this code as an example which works in firefox, but in webkit browsers, there is a weird margin on the right as well as the left. In this example code I set the container width to 600px for easy demonstration, but in actuality I won't know the width of the container div. I'm using doctype XHTML 1.0 Transitional.

```
<style type="text/css">
#container {
  height:50px; width:600px; background-color:black; overflow:hidden;
}
#sidebar {
  height:50px; width:100px; background-color:lightgreen; float:left;
}
#content {
  height:50px; margin-left:100px; background-color:lightblue;
}
</style>

<div id="container">
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its pretty much okay to me.  I threw it in a JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/chprpipr/9fuDw/  The only change I made was to remove the 10px padding that body contained, but I think that's a style that JsFiddle might have been adding.

Comment: @chprpipr hmmm... it does look good... maybe it's just with my doctype?

Comment: I updated the doctype to XHTML 1.0 Transitional in the fiddle, but it still looks good.  Maybe compare your doctype to the fiddle to see if there's a syntax error?  Or you could copy your code into a fiddle and reproduce it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh... well I had `div {overflow:hidden;}` in my global css. Setting `overflow:visible` on the content div made it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
          <style type="text/css">
#container {
  height:50px; width:100%; background-color:black; overflow:hidden; float:left;
}
#sidebar {
  height:50px; width:200px; background-color:lightgreen; float:left;
}
#content {
  height:50px; background-color:lightblue;
}
</style>
```